# Alias with Join in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm having some issues with a many to many relationship with a simple ACL module I'm developing.

I have three tables:

Groups

- *id_group
- name

Permissions

- *id_permission
- name

RelPermissionsGroup

- *id_relation
- group
- permission

So I had this query

```
SELECT * FROM acl_groups 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acl_RelPermissionsGroup 
  ON acl_groups.id_group = acl_RelPermissionsGroup.group 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acl_permissions 
  ON acl_permissions.id_permission = acl_RelPermissionsGroup.permission 
WHERE id_group > 0
```

If I do the query in phpmyadmin it shows fine. So, it shows all groups whether they have permissions or not and if they have it also shows them.

I see one problem here and it is that the name attribute is repeated. How can I alias every single field?
But that's not the problem.

The problem is that doing mysqli_fetch_assoc performs fine except for the group that doesn't have any permissions. This is what outputs:

```
    Array ( 
[id_group] => 2 
[name] => 
[id_relation] => 
[group] => 
[permission] => 
[id_permission] => 
)
```

The group ID is fine but given the fact that fields are duplicated it overrides them. Also, id_group and id_permission seems to be duplicated with group and permission respectively.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to name the fields explicitly, like so

```
SELECT
  ag.name as group_name
  ,ap.name as permission_name
  ,ar.`group` as permission_group_id 
FROM acl_groups ag 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acl_RelPermissionsGroup ar ON ag.id_group = ar.`group` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acl_permissions ap ON ap.id_permission = ar.permission 
WHERE id_group > 0
```

Don't forget that `group` is a reserved word and needs to be quoted in backticks `` `group` `` like so.

Comment: It works! And I were able to choose how many fields should I show. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You should write 'SELECT groups.id_group group_id, groups.name as group_name ...'